# Why is straight-on viewing of inexpensive LCD screens no longer the best angle?

Tags: display, lcd, tablet, led, ergonomics

I bought several inexpensive tablets in a range of sizes.  Each is from a different manufacturer.  I have not taken them apart, but using a magnifying glass, I can tell that each screen appears to be using a slightly different LCD (LED illuminated) manufacturing processes.

What is **common across all the screens** is that viewing them straight-on is not the best viewing angle.  Tilting them about 10 degrees generates the best results.

What's interesting is that, historically, you needed to view inexpensive LCD (LED illuminated) screens straight-on for the best results.  Any angle diverging from straight-on resulted in poor image quality.

What has changed in LCD (LED illuminated) manufacturing technology that viewing them straight-on is no longer the best angle?

Comment: I think your premise is incorrect.  I've seen spec sheets for old monochrome LCD panels, and they had an optimal viewing angle slightly below orthogonal.

Comment: @sawdust That's very interesting.  Were those specs for illuminated or reflective displays?  BTW, I think I convoluted the issue by interchangeably using LCD and LED, when I really meant LED.

Comment: The spec sheets were for reflective panels.  Backlighting was quite rare back then.  BTW please avoid using "LED" for "LCD with LED backlighting".  To promote the backlight method to the status of the display technology is misleading, and is purely a marketing (not a technical) terminology.

Comment: @sawdust You are correct.  When I submitted this question, I used LCD most of the time.  Then I read your comment, which made me realize that using LCD was a bit misleading because I'm not talking about old reflective panels.  I'll try another edit to see if I can improve the wording. :-)

Comment: Yes, LED backlighting has nothing to do with this issue.  Look into TN LCD screen technology, which is cheap, versus something like IPS screens, which have much larger viewing angles. http://www.tnpanel.com/tn-vs-ips-va/

Comment: @paradroid I agree, but even old TN screens had better viewing characteristics and angles than many modern LCD (LED illuminated) screens.  On all these different tablets I bought, if I tilt them more than 20 degrees, they look horrible.  In some directions, tilting them just 5 degrees causes serious distortions of color and contrast.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard That is the nature of cheap TN screens I'm afraid..  I'm using a TN screen on a ThinkPad T410 and it is much better than others I have used, with regard to viewing angles, but still not anything as good as my X220 or Dell Ultrasharp desktop monitors.  TVs are always IPS, for the viewing angles.

Comment: @paradroid Interesting.  I don't hear people complaining about most mid-range tablet screens.  Maybe I just haven't read the complaints, or they are all IPS.  For example, is the Fire 7 an IPS screen?  I thought the Fire 7 was TN and the Fire HD 6 was IPS.  But I can't find reliable specs with that much detail.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard On non-touch monitors, it is easy to see if it is TN or IPS by pressing on the screen with your finger.  IPS screens do not distort in the way TN screens do, but this test obviously would not work on a touch screen tablet. (Also, it seems that some TN screens distort more than others, as the [hi-res] TN screen on this ThinkPad T410 does not distort easily.)